# Email Template {!Receiving_User.Name}

Tags: email, email-template, approval-process, merge-field, public-group

I want to send email to all the users in a public group from initial approval action. How can I refer individual user's name in the email template? 
I tried {!Receiving_User.field_name} merge field in custom email template, but it isn't working.

I read that the {!Receiving_User.field_name} and {!Sending_User.field_name} merge fields work only for mass email. Doesn't sending emails to public group come under this category?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried {!Target_User} ?It is available in the list as Workflow Target User .

Comment: Workflow Target User Merge Fields reference fields from the user record that was created or updated to trigger the workflow rule. See release note for details - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_workflow_user_merge_fields.htm